# Cant hide status bar in iOS7 with plist

Tags: objective-c

I tried to add to the plist this row :

`View controller-based status bar appearance"` setter to `NO` .

Still see the status bar.

How can i remove it ?

Comment: There is no method to hide status bar in iOS7."View controller-based status bar appearance" is NO, just means status bar showed not based view controllers.

Comment: http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/61507315630/wrestling-with-status-bars-and-navigation-bars-on-ios-7  about iOS7 status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this in your AppDelegate and remember to set "Status bar is initially hidden" to YES in your info .plist

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In your appDelegate do this:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)